# Modal not showing proper video in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, axios

Hi I'm implementing a sample app with react,I'm also using youtube api search and react bootstrap.

The idea is the following, I enter a search term, for example "PS4" this will call **youtube api search** and will bring back 5 matching results in a json format.
With this json, I render a list of thumbnails with videos, title, description,(similar to youtube website). if I click on one of the thumbnails, the idea is to display a modal dialog with the video inside. Here's the problem, *it's always loading the same video.*

*I omit the imports at the beginning of the file*

**VideoList.js**

```
   class VideoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.close = this.close.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        }
    }

    openModal(video) {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    }
    close() {
        this.setState({ showModal: false });
    }

    render() {
        const videoItems = this.props.videos.map(video =>
            <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                <Thumbnail onClick={() => this.openModal(video)}
                    className="thumbnail"
                    src={video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url}
                    alt={video.snippet.description}
                    key={uid()}
                >
                    <h3>{video.title}</h3>
                    <p>{video.snippet.description}</p>
                    <hr />
                    <i>Date: {video.snippet.publishedAt}</i>
                    <VideoView show={this.state.showModal} video={video} close={this.close} />
                </Thumbnail>
            </Col>
        );
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    {videoItems}
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

export default VideoList;
```

**VideoView.js**

```
   const VideoView = props => {
    if (!props) {
        return <div>{'Could not load the video'}</div>
    }
    return (
        <div className="static-modal">
            <Modal show={props.show}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>{props.video.snippet.title}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body>
                    One fine body...
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={() => props.close()}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}

export default VideoView;
```

If I click on one of the thumbnails, a modal popup shows with the video (some information of it, not the video itself), the thing is that it always shows the last video (*the last in the list of thumbnails*)

**Another thing:** I'm facing a design problem here because I think I should delegate the **onclose** action to the modal dialog, in this case, the **VideoView** however  the videoView component is a stateless component, I'm only sending some props to render it, (check the onclose callback). Is this a correct approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create multiple `VideoView` elements sharing the same prop `this.state.showModal`. It means that when `this.state.showModal` is `true` then you show all modals at once, and you see only one of them which is on top. Create one `VideoView` element and pass it a video to show. Also to show/hide modal you can check if `this.state.video` is not equal to `null` - if it have value assigned then modal should be visible.

```
class VideoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.close = this.close.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            video: null
        }
    }

    openModal(video) {
        this.setState({ video: video });
    }
    close() {
        this.setState({ video: null });
    }

    render() {
        const videoItems = this.props.videos.map(video =>
            <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                <Thumbnail onClick={() => this.openModal(video)}
                    className="thumbnail"
                    src={video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url}
                    alt={video.snippet.description}
                    key={uid()}
                >
                    <h3>{video.title}</h3>
                    <p>{video.snippet.description}</p>
                    <hr />
                    <i>Date: {video.snippet.publishedAt}</i>
                </Thumbnail>
            </Col>
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid>
                    <Row>
                        {videoItems}
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
                <VideoView show={this.state.video !== null} video={this.state.video} close={this.close} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default VideoList;
```

Comment: I get the point, but I just tried that, and it gives me the following error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$luvdyumrrro0emieyt2sgiudi' of null
    at Object.u [as getClosestInstanceFromNode] (compiled.js:7)

this only happens if I render the VideoView component with the props I'm sending. If I remove all the props and render the modal dialog without any information, it's working fine. eg if I put this line in videoView {props.video.snippet.title} the error shows. I google it but I couldn't find anything useful

Comment: You need to debug this case. Add `console.log(props.video)` there to see if there are any null references. I.e. check that `props.video.snippet.title` always exists.